# TextArea in Elm

Tags: elm

I am trying to use the elm [form demo](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Intermediate/Form.elm) as the basis for my app, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make a text area instead of the 1 line input? What am I missing

Comment: This question is very out of date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be possible now with [elm-html](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#textarea). It's a library to add any html directly, so textareas should be easy to work with.

It's new, so documentation and examples are sparse, but this should change.

Here's an example document editor, written in Elm, with textareas:
http://dreamwriter.io

and the code:
https://github.com/rtfeldman/dreamwriter

Answer (score 15):

This answer can be updated now:

```
textarea [ cols 40, rows 10, placeholder "...", onInput ... ] []
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Sadly text areas are currently not supported.

If they were I would have expected [documentation](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/Graphics-Input-Field). 
There was an old [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elm-discuss/pdahWkXjzxk/discussion)/[PR](https://github.com/elm-lang/Elm/pull/358) about adding it, which refers to how the ability to resize a text area makes it slightly more complicated than single line inputs.

Ultimately though, I think it's just a matter of nobody having needed it.

**Advice:** I think it's a good idea to bring up this lacking feature on mailing list. The release of Elm 0.13 was pushed back recently, so you might just be able to convince Evan to add the text area to it before releasing.